# Sorting using a three number comparator

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of size n waiting to be sorted. But different from ordinary sorting problem, I'm constrained to use a specific comparator, which receives three numbers and tells the maximum and minimum of the three. My goal is to use the comparator as few times as possible before completely sorting the array. What strategy can I use?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What strategy have you tried? :)

Comment: I fail to figure out how to use the information provided by one comparison sufficiently (In theory, it should divide my times of comparison by three).

Comment: Besides, the performance of the algorithm should be uniform, so the worst case is still O(nlogn). I'm considering quicksort or mergesort.

Comment: So you put in three numbers and get back two? How are you supposed to figure out which input was the middle number (without comparing the two outputs to the three inputs again)? (Also, if you're asking about the algorithm, that has nothing to do with C++...)

Comment: For example, if I put in 1,2,3, the comparator tells me the index of the maximum and minimum of a[1],a[2],a[3]. Say a[1] is maximum and a[2] is minimum, then a[3] is middle.

Comment: @worstcoder We return a value from the comparator with respect to `a`, `b` or `c` from the pool of numbers `a,b,c`?

Comment: Yeah. The comparator is like "void compare(int a, int b, int c, int *max, int *min);".

Comment: Dunno what to do about the best strategy, but you could compare two numbers using you comparator by providing a dummy third value as `(a + b) / 2`. This, at least, allows you to implement any of the usual algorithms.

Comment: Implementing usual algorithms is easy. Put in a,b,b, and it decays to ordinary comparator.

Comment: Huh, now I'm genuinely ashamed i didn't think of this, came with mean value instead =D

Comment: In theory the comparator is equal to three ordinary comparator, so the advantage has to be used.

Comment: The advantage of the three-comparator cannot be harvested by sorting schemes which expect two-comparator info. You'd have to adapt write a sorting algorithm yourself. Interesting. Quicksort3, which partitions into three instead of two. But the best two-sorters are probably not the best three-sorters. I recommend to start with a working, easily understandable sorter, e.g. bubble sort. Adapt to three-way and work on based on the experience gathered.

Comment: It's a good question but possibly too broad on the grounds this could be PhD thesis material. There are 3 partition sorts out there, but you'd also need a corresponding 3 way swap. In the end using a qsort with "a, a, b" passed to the callback may well be the fastest thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came up with an idea.

Let's remember how quicksort works:

- First, we locate a sort of a median value (pick up `(a[0] + a[N-1])/2` if you're too lazy =3).
- Then, we divide an array
  by two on the condition of being less or greater than median.
- At last, we run the algorithm recursively on each of two subarrays

Using your comparator, you can speed up your second phase twice by processing two values at once:

- `compare(median, a[2 * i], a[2 * i + 1])`
- if min is median, both are greater and go to the right subarray
- if max is median, both are less and go to the left subarray
- if neither is median, min goes left, and max goes right

After that, run recursive part of the algorithm as usual.

Comment: It seems nice. But I think it's possible to decay to O(n^2) in worst case.

Comment: Well, basic quicksort IS O(n^2) in worst case. Taking mean of random N elements in the array as median can sorta fix it, but it is still possible. You can't really go against theory with quicksort.

Comment: At least, suggested approach doesn't really change an original algorithm even a little. And, quicksort is accepted as default sort by most of the compilers and languages, so it should be safe enough to use it.

Comment: Checking "if min is median" seems to require to use `==`, which might be unavailable. I wonder if this exercise is supposed to be solved assuming the comparator is all we have.

Comment: Yeah, if we assume that we can't check for equality, this is completely different and more complex task.

Comment: No, the min and max pointer carries only the index, so the method works.

Answer (score 2):

Since your three-way comparator can be implemented by three calls to a normal comparator, that means we can't improve on any normal sorting algorithm by a factor of more than 3. A more careful argument shows that, because each three-way comparison gives us log₂ 6 ≈ 2.585 bits of information, we can't improve by a factor of more than that. Intuitively, when sorting with a normal comparator you might compare `a <= b` and `b <= c`, and therefore not need to compare `a` and `c` anyway; so the possible speedup factor could be as small as 2.

So asymptotically, we're still looking for an O(*n* log *n*) algorithm, and the question is how to exploit the comparator to do fewer comparisons by at least a factor 2. The "obvious" thing to try first is modifying an existing comparison-based sorting algorithm; a good candidate is bottom-up [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), which does about *n* log₂ *n* comparisons in the average case, and 1.5 *n* log₂ *n* in the worst case ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Bottom-up_heapsort)). This beats the standard quicksort algorithm, which does about 1.39 *n* log₂ *n* comparisons in the average case ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis)).

The algorithm works using two basic operations on a heap, "sift down" and "sift up".

- The "sift down" operation requires comparing a parent element with its two children, to see if the parent element is greater than or equal to both its children, or if not, which child the parent should be swapped with. We can use the three-way comparator to compare the parent with both children at once.
- The "sift up" operation compares a child with its parent, and swaps them if they are out of order; this is then repeated all the way up to the root node. We can use the three-way comparator to compare the child node with its parent and its grandparent at once.

The heapsort algorithm only calls the comparator within those two operations, and for both operations the three-way comparator can be called fewer times by a factor of 2. This isn't necessarily the best you can do, but it starts from a very efficient algorithm, and matches the worst-case speedup factor given by intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I get an brilliant idea. Using 4-way mergesort and loser tree to optimize, the times of using the comparator can be reduced to less than 0.5nlog₂n, by my rough estimate.